# phpbb3 cannot display thai encoding from database

Tags: mysql

I am converting `smf` to `phpbb3` . I am running `phpbb` on wamp . i made changes in `php.ini`.

```
;default-charset="tis620"
```

i made changes in queries of database table

```
 columnname varchar(255) CHARACTER SET tis620 NOT NULL DEFAULT
```

I have added language pack in phpbb3 forum .i also tried changing advance setting of google chrome to thai language but still it is not working although ,In  phpmyadmin the encoding of thai is displayed properly but it cant display on forum on localhost. it is displaying characters

on localhost like this

```
  "ÁÕàÃ×èÍ§à¡èÒæÁÒãËé¾ÕèªèÇÂ¤ÃÑº "
```

Answer (score 0):

Set character set to `tis-620`

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=tis-620">
```